# React.js w/ react-router: Should my components 'react' to the changes in url or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, state

My question is more about high-level design decisions regarding my app's routing, and the subsequent components that get rendered.

My app has multiple "pages" / "sections". Navigating to these sections can be handled simply with basic routing. One of these sections is a 'lookbook' and has a photofeed like that of Instagram (the route is "/lookbook"). If I were to click on a photo in this photofeed I want a modal to appear with the expanded photo with some extra data.

**My question boils down to what should happen on the onClick event of one of these photos in the feed. (This very specific functionality is the source of my question because I believe it will determine how I should design how the component acts.)**

In the onClick event, does it make more sense to:

**A)** Simply navigate to a route, something like "/lookbook/photoId". And then have the parent Lookbook component sense the URL change and then just serve what I want.

or

**B)** Change the state of the Lookbook component in a way that expands the clicked photo inside a modal (No URL change).

Comment: I would almost certainly do B for a modal, though that may just be a personal preference.. I can't say it's objectively correct

Comment: I would say A has its advantages. You're using URL state for other things, so its cleaner to continue using that state, and it also provides a way to directly go to that state. if it was component state then you couldn't navigate directly to the photo opened up in a modal, which may be a nice use case

Comment: Good point. I do want to implement shareable URL's so A seems to be in that direction. Now, if I were to go down the A path, what should the routing be like? Would my nested route (i.e 'lookbook/photoId') render the Parent Lookbook component which then senses that the url has an id nested with it, or would my nested route render a deeper child component of Lookbook.js such as PhotoModal.js for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question almost entirely depends on how you like to think of the problem.

A has definite advantages. It is cleaner, probably easier to code and would be my first choice. Each photo would direct you to a different URL based on the ID and a **separate component** altogether would cater to it.

B on the other hand would make your photoID part of the parent component(index page's) state. Depending on this state, you could create your modal. This would make your component a little more complicated than A, but here, you have just one component doing the whole job, and division of responsibility between your components is clear.

Either way is absolutely right and it depends on how you think of your components and the objective served by each of them.

Comment: I think this answer solves my concerns. You explain how and why both can be valid depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in react, you should pass callback function to your feed component and on clicking the feed image change the state of the lookback component using callback function. This is the react approach, now all depends on you whether the state change denotes URL change or modal state change.

Comment: The last part of your answer, are you saying that I can trigger a change in the URL which then triggers a change in state or are you saying that I trigger a change in state which then triggers a change in the URL?

Comment: React is totally based on state and it has nothing to do with url changes,  you do anything without even considering the url change.

Comment: Vaibhav, yes I get that. But if I want to implement shareable URL's, for sharing on social media, shouldn't my components be URL driven? (URL determines the state).

Comment: Oh my bad, yes surely if there is something that is url driven, then what can be done is, for every feed store its details such as url etc in state. And whatever is there in the state object display it in the browser.